# Ocaml list.map error this function is applied to too many arguments

Tags: ocaml

Hello I am new to Ocaml and I am trying to play around with List and list.map. So I write a function helper which takes a list and creates a list of lists.

```
let rec helper l= 
  match l with 
  | []->[[]]
  | x::xs -> [x]::helper xs;;
```

Now when i try to use list.map to concatenate to each member of this list of list i get an error.

`List.map(fun y->[1]@y) helper [1;2;3];;`

`Error: This function is applied to too many arguments;
maybe you forgot a`;'`

I am unable to understand why is this error causes. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need `()` for `helper [1;2;3]`

i.e., `List.map(fun y->[1]@y) (helper [1;2;3])`.

This will remove the error.